# What does the syntax ->* mean?

Tags: abap

I have read some documents about the syntax `->*`, but i still don't get it. Can anyone explain what it means and in what scenarios I can use it?

I have that syntax in this example:

```
assign ovs_callback_object->query_parameters->* to <ls_query_params> CASTING.
```

Comment: @isherwood Not in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `->*` operator is the "Dereference" operator. It turns a `TYPE REF TO something` into a `TYPE something`.

In your example, `ovs_callback_object->query_parameters` is likely a reference, but you don't want to assign the reference to the field-symbol, you want to assign the actual field the reference points to.

Answer (score 3):

`refvar->*` is used to de-reference an unstructured reference variable. For a structured reference, you would use `structref->component` to access a component of the referenced object (an attribute of an object or a component of a structure). If you have something like `TYPE REF TO i`, there's no inner structure, so you have to use the special syntax `->*`. [It's all in the documentation...](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_702/en/abendata_references.htm)